# Calories burnt by fidgiting?

Tags: calories

I am wondering if there is any significant calorie burning from fidgeting (bouncing your heel, tapping your foot, moving your fingers, etc.) LiveStrong has an [article](http://www.livestrong.com/article/320945-the-calories-burned-shaking-a-leg/) on this discussing Non-Exercise Activity Thermogenesis, claiming fidget-ers burned up to 350 more calories per day. Is there any merit to this claim or benefit to fidgeting throughout the work day?

Comment: You might find [this article interesting](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=99521&page=1), which even sites some studies. But I really don't think it will add up to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little misguided, because if you read the Livestrong article carefully:

> Those who fidget more by shaking their leg, repositioning themselves, **standing up and walking around**, and so forth can burn 350 more calories per day than their more sedentary counterparts, according to Levine at U.S. News & World Report.

Standing up and walking isn't really considered fidgeting, so yes, the subjects consumed up to 350 kcal/day more, but not by wiggling their feet or rocking a pen (the definition of fidgeting).

As a comparison, let's compare how many calories I'd burn sitting down vs standing [using this online calculator](http://www.juststand.org/tabid/637/language/en-US/default.aspx):

- If Standing while working: 1496 kcal burned
- If Sitting while working: 1152 kcal burned
- Calorie-burn increase: **344 kcal**

So just standing all day would give the desired number of calories. Imagine if I'd fidgeted while standing! Or even better, use any of [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000VICRO8) [devices:](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000AMX3AM)

[image][image]

Which would seriously boost your calories compared to just sitting down.

Interestingly, the author of the study (dr. J. Levine) about Non-Exercise Activity Thermogenesis (NEAT) [was interviewed by USA Today](http://www.usatoday.com/news/health/weightloss/2009-01-21-fidget-activity_N.htm) and they included the following picture:

[image]

[In the interview he gives some solid advice:](http://www.usatoday.com/news/health/weightloss/2009-01-21-fidget-activity_N.htm)

> We need to move more throughout the day. The key is to find what you
>   enjoy doing.
>
> Simple examples include a quick walk around the block before your
>   morning shower; a 30-minute walk at lunch; having a couple of
>   walk-and-talk meetings during the day (research shows you'll think
>   better); pacing when you're talking on the phone; taking a 15-minute
>   catch-up walk after work with your partner; walking with your children
>   and listening to their music with them; doing some active volunteering
>   such as taking a stressed mom's children out for a walk or bringing a
>   meal to an elderly person.
>
> If you incorporate some of these ideas into your day, you burn an
>   extra 500 to 1,000 calories.

He goes on to answer your actual question:

> **Q: Does fidgeting promote weight loss?**
>
> A: **In terms of calorie burn or weight loss, fidgeting doesn't help
>   you.** The research we conducted demonstrated that the secret to burning
>   fat was to get up, move and walk. We found that people can increase
>   their NEAT by 800 calories a day and resist gaining weight, even when
>   they eat too much. At first the world's press mistook NEAT for being a
>   fidgeting phenomenon, but we pointed out that you would never be able
>   to fidget enough to burn 800 calories a day.
>
> Fidgeting is your body's way of telling you to get up and move. Our
>   body wants to move, but the environment suppresses it.

**So to conclude: no fidgeting is not enough.** If you really want to burn some calories, you need to get off your ass and get some work done. With Fitness, there's no such thing as a free lunch!

Comment: I noticed the keywords "standing up and walking around" in the article- prompting me to ask the question. Thanks for sharing the interview q/a